# django fail migrations with mysql - TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'CustomUser

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration

we had our project working with sqlite, but when tried to use mysql as db, we encountered this problem:

```
    PS C:\GitHub\Javagochi\javagochi-server> python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, items, javagochi, sessions, sites, trades, users
Running migrations:
  Applying javagochi.0003_auto_20190330_1208...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 523, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 627, in _alter_field
    new_default = self.effective_default(new_field)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 239, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 937, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 790, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 956, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 965, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'CustomUser'
```

as a foreign key (we think) in this class of the model

```
class Javagochi(models.Model):
race = models.ForeignKey(JavagochiBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, db_column='user__id')

nickname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
current_health = models.IntegerField()
current_hunger = models.IntegerField()
current_cold = models.IntegerField()
current_hot = models.IntegerField()
current_age = models.IntegerField(default=1)
current_level = models.IntegerField(default=1)
current_experience = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nickname + ', ' + self.race.race
```

and this is our custom user

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
username = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
level = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
exp = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
coins = models.IntegerField(default = 1000)
# image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

we think the problem is django tries to use the object CustomUser as foreign key (instead of its identifier), but can't seem to solve it.

Comment: Please show the contents of the `0003_auto_20190330_1208` migration.

Comment: But also, why have you used `username` as the primary key on CustomUser? Apart from anything else, that will mean users can't change their usernames (as all related objects will be out of sync). What's the point of doing this?

Comment: Also also, why are you doing `db_column='user__id'` on `Javagochi.owner`?